# To sort array based on startdtate and present job or no

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am making a dynamic portfolio for myself using VueJS.
I created a way to update experiences and order it based on currently ongoing jobs showing first sorted in ascending order meaning a job with start date May 2021 will show first and then March 2021 (both being present).
Next, if I set an end date for the job, it should update and place the current jobs in the front which isn't happening.

Algorithm:

```
newExp() {
    this.editableExperience.sort((a,b) => {
        a = a.period.split(' - ');
        b = b.period.split(' - ');
        let aStartDate = a[0];
        let aEndDate = a[1];
        let bStartDate = b[0];
        let bEndDate = b[1];
        if (aEndDate == 'Present' && bEndDate == 'Present') {
            return new Date(bStartDate) - new Date(aStartDate);
        } else if (aEndDate == 'Present') {
            return a;
        } else if (bEndDate == 'Present') {
            return b;
        } else {
            return new Date(bStartDate) - new Date(aStartDate);
        }
    })
    this.experience = this.editableExperience;
}
```

editableExperience is an array of experiences: (I have added only required information)

```
editableExperience = [{period: 'May 2021 - Present'}, {period: 'November 2020 - Present'}, {period: 'January 2021 - March 2021'}, {period: 'March 2018 - July 2020'}]
```

Exact issue situation:

1. Setting the third element to present job brings it to position 2 but giving it an end date again does not send it to position 3 again.
2. Setting the last element to present does not bring it in front of the non-present jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compare function is returning a string or a number while the compare function should return either 1, 0 or -1 as per the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

I have made changes to your code below:

```
newExp() {
        this.editableExperience.sort((a,b) => {
            a = a.period.split(' - ');
            b = b.period.split(' - ');
            let aStartDate = a[0];
            let aEndDate = a[1];
            let bStartDate = b[0];
            let bEndDate = b[1];
            if (aEndDate == 'Present' && bEndDate == 'Present') {
                return (new Date(bStartDate) - new Date(aStartDate)) > 1 ? 1 : -1;
            } else if (aEndDate == 'Present') {
                return -1;
            } else if (bEndDate == 'Present') {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return (new Date(bStartDate) - new Date(aStartDate)) > 1 ? 1 : -1;
            }
        });
       this.experience = this.editableExperience;
  }
```

Comment: My bad, I did not go through the docs. It works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The view model is a little bit mixed with data model, I would suggest to keep a clean data model which hold the original values, it is good for processing like sort. then a a computed property as view model which is depend on the data model.

```
data: () => ({
  editableExperience: [
    {start: 202105, end: 999999},
    {start: 202011, end: 999999},
    {start: 202101, end: 202103},
    {start: 201803, end: 202107},
  ],
}),
```

then the sorting will looks like:

```
this.editableExperience.sort((a,b) => {
  return b['end'] === a['end']? b['start'] - a['start'] : b['end'] - a['end']
})
```

for your view(display)

```
computed: {
  viewExperiences() {
    const ve = []
    for(const e of this.editableExperience) {
      ve.push(this.getExperienceDisplay(e))
    }
    return ve
  }
},
methods: {
  formatExperienceDate(dateInt) {
    if(dateInt === 999999) return 'Present'
    const dateStr = dateInt.toString()
    const date = new Date(dateStr.substring(0, 4) + '-' + dateStr.substring(4, 6))
    return date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", {year: 'numeric', month: 'long'})
  },
  getExperienceDisplay(exp) {
    const startDate = this.formatExperienceDate(exp['start'])
    const endDate = this.formatExperienceDate(exp['end'])
    return `${startDate} - ${endDate}`
  },
}
```